# SQL group by query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, union-all

I have a a UNION ALL on two result sets. This results in some like below.

TOTALSTABLE

```
FAMILYNAME-----FIRSTNAME------NUMBER------TOTAL
Brown          Dave           1234        500.00
Brown          Dave           1234        300.00
Smith          Frank          4321        123.00
Smith          Frank          4321        456.00
```

I run the following query...

```
SELECT TOTALSTABLE.FAMILYNAME,
  TOTALSTABLE.FIRSTNAME,
  TOTALSTABLE.NUMBER,
  SUM(TOTALSTABLE.TOTAL) COMBINEDTOTAL
FROM TOTALSTABLE
GROUP BY TOTALSTABLE.FAMILYNAME,
  TOTALSTABLE.FIRSTNAME,
  TOTALSTABLE.NUMBER
```

Which gives me something like...

```
FAMILYNAME-----FIRSTNAME------NUMBER------COMBINEDTOTAL
Brown          Dave           1234        800.00
Smith          Frank          4321        579.00
```

This is what i need. However I need to add an additional column which is null in the result i am attempting to do a UNION ALL on.

Example:

T1

```
FAMILYNAME-----FIRSTNAME------NUMBER------TOTAL-------DATE
Brown          Dave           1234        500.00      01/01/2001
Smith          Frank          4321        123.00      01/01/2001
```

T2

```
FAMILYNAME-----FIRSTNAME------NUMBER------TOTAL-------DATE
Brown          Dave           1234        300.00      NULL
Smith          Frank          4321        456.00      NULL
```

COMBINED (UNION ALL)

```
FAMILYNAME-----FIRSTNAME------NUMBER------TOTAL-------DATE
Brown          Dave           1234        500.00      01/01/2001
Brown          Dave           1234        300.00      NULL
Smith          Frank          4321        123.00      01/01/2001
Smith          Frank          4321        456.00      NULL
```

I need to get the combined total like in the first example, using the date that isnt null.

Example of desired results.

```
FAMILYNAME-----FIRSTNAME------NUMBER------COMBINEDTOTAL----DATE
Brown          Dave           1234        800.00           01/01/2001
Smith          Frank          4321        579.00           01/01/2001
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to do here? Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just want

```
SELECT familyName,
       firstName,
       number,
       SUM(total) combinedTotal,
       MAX(date) date
  FROM (<<union all query>>)
 GROUP BY familyName,
          firstName, 
          number
```

Answer (score -1):

AS you state, you can try follow code

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM T2 
) T
WHERE T.c3 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY T.c1, T.c2, T.c3
```